# Emotion or stickers for cordova or phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

Could you please let me know how we can call android and Iphone Emoji keyboard using cordova?

Basically I am creating chat app it that I need to have smiley, so I am thinking to enable the keyboard so that user can select it from there.

any other idea please help me.

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also interested by the solution @user1417429, did you find anything about that?

Comment: no not yet? Do you have anything till now?

Comment: I think with apple devices the user has to enable the emoji keyboard as mentioned here: [enable emoji in ios](http://mashable.com/2014/06/17/emoji-on-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

@Gallwynmasc you can also able to enable emoji keyboard mannually like below described:

Navigate to Settings > Language and input > Google Keyboard settings
Tap Add-on Dictionaries under the text correction subheading
Download and install Emoji for English Words (or your favourite language, if available). It might be possible that you have to refresh the Add-on Dictionaries first.